# Kubernetes ingress not routing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have 2 services and deployments deployed on minikube on local dev. Both are accessible when I run minikube start service. For the sake of simplicity I have attached code with only one service

However, ingress routing is not working

CoffeeApiDeployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: coffeeapi-deployment
  labels:
    app: coffeeapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: coffeeapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: coffeeapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: coffeeapi
        image: manigupta31286/coffeeapi:latest
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
          value: "http://+"
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: "Development"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coffeeapi-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: coffeeapi
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30036
```

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /coffee
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: coffeeapi-service
              port: 
                number: 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the ingress class in the spec.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # (or the class you configured)
```

Using `NodePort` on your service may also be problematic. At least it's not required since you want to use the ingress controller to route traffic via the `ClusterIP` and not use the `NodePort` directly.